# Using digital signature and image input button in one file

Tags: javascript, css, pdf-generation, antenna-house

I need to create PDF forms using Antenna House Formatter.
The forms need to have both digital-signature and image-input fields.

The digital signature with AHF-CSS works on its own:

```
input.signature{
    display: -ah-form-field;
    -ah-field-type: signature;
}
```

As does the image-input HTML/JavaScript:

```
<meta name="openaction"
    content="#JavaScript=            
        var f = this.getField('imageInput');      
        f.setAction('MouseUp', 'event.target.buttonImportIcon();');
"/>
```

But if I use both together and try to enter a digital signature I get the message:

> The document cannot be signed in its current state. Please save the
> document, close it, reopen it, and then attempt to sign again.

Saving and reopening does not fix the problem. Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to ask Antenna House Support about this. (You could do it if your maintenance is current.) Their answer:

---

I don't think it will be possible with Formatter and CSS.  The 'OpenAction' script modifies the document with this code:

```
f.setAction('MouseUp', 'event.target.buttonImportIcon();');
```

Even if you save the document the 'OpenAction' script will run again and modify it.

With XSL-FO you could avoid an OpenAction script by just setting the 'MouseUp' value directly:

```
<axf:form-field-event name="MouseUp" action-type="javascript">
    event.target.buttonImportIcon();
</axf:form-field-event>
```

'form-field-event' isn't available with CSS.

One horrible work around is to add a check in the 'OpenAction' script to see if the button was already modified.  Ex:

```
var f = this.getField('imageInput');

    if (color.equal(f.fillColor, color.red)) {
       /* do nothing, this will happen after document is saved */
    } else {
       f.fillColor = color.red;
       f.setAction('MouseUp', 'event.target.buttonImportIcon();');
    }
```

You could 'save' the Formatter generated PDF in Acrobat and then the saved result could get the signature.

---

There might also or instead be a place to set `this.dirty = false;` so that the document isn't seen as modified. (I've previously used `this.dirty = false;` in a JavaScript function that toggles layers off and on: I didn't want to be prompted to save the document on closing just because some layers had changed visibility.)

Comment: Due to time constraints I used the workaround. 
We don't have anyone with XSL-FO expertise and an Acrobat license would take several weeks to obtain having to our procurement department.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for that.